# how to retrieve the internet data usage on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have learnt that we need to import private APIs  in order to programmatically retrieve the internet data usage.but it goes in vain as app store forbids users from accessing private APIs. many answers got from various other sources said its present in the genera-settings-usage. but how to get it programmatically?how to fetch the bytes of data from when the user has logged in? and how to do it in ios4 without using any servers?

Comment: You can track the data usage of of your own app, not of others.

Comment: This is not true see [this](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for solution and found it here: [iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring)
Please take a look this post, it provides all info that you need.